# code to replace int array's element's least significant bit to 0 in java

Tags: java

```
int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);

int rgb[] = new int[] {
    ((argb >> 16) & 0xff),    //red
    (argb >> 8) & 0xff ,     //green
    (argb) & 0xff     //blue
};
```

this the array and i want to replace least significant bit of each element from zero???

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as `... & 0xFE` instead of `0xFF`?

Comment: But the OP is clearly moving each character to the range 0x00–0xFF anyway — so it's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

following code may helpful to you. try this.
 for (int i = 0; i < rgb.length; ++i) {
        rgb[i] &= 0xfffffffe;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```
    int i = 33;
    System.out.printf("%d\n%32s\n", i, Integer.toBinaryString(i));

    i = (i >> 1) << 1;   // this does the job.

    System.out.printf("%d\n%32s\n", i, Integer.toBinaryString(i));
```

(My previous reply was actually incorrect)

Comment: @user1939093 my previous reply was incorrect. Corrected it now.